# Removing myself from projects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

Last year, I used the Google cloud platform when teaching my class, so all of my students added me as a member to their projects. I now have dozens of abandoned projects showing up in my cloud console. Is there any way I can stop seeing them short of tracking down dozens of past students?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about applications or projects?
Could you try to:
1- Visit [1]
2- Select one of the projects
3- Click on 'Permissions'
4- Click on 'Remove'

[1] https://appengine.google.com/

Comment: Hi Adrian, I am talking about projects. When I go to the project's permission tab, I don't have an option to remove myself because I am not the owner of the project.

Comment: Hi Mike, did you try to remove yourself from the applications?
I clicked on 'Remove' and it also removed me from the project

Comment: What application? When I go to cloud.google.com, it just shows me a list of projects. Note that these are Google Compute Engine projects. We were not using AppEngine

Comment: If the projects are not very old, when you create a project, also an application is created.
I have done a test: I have created a new project with an instance but I haven't used AppEngine. Then I have invited me to using another email address and I can remove myself visiting: https://appengine.google.com/

You can take a look if you can see there your projects. If not, probably the only way for the moment is to ask each student to remove your account from their projects.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the author didn't use AppEngine and used only the Developers Console to manage his projects, he had to follow the next steps to remove himself from the projects:

1. Visit the [App Engine dashboard](https://appengine.google.com/)
2. Select one of the projects
3. Click on 'Permissions'
4. Click on 'Remove'

And repeat the process for each project.

PS: The Developers Console doesn't include all the functionality yet and in this case it is needed to visit the AppEngine Console.

Comment: This only works if you're the project owner. Project editors are still SOL.